# Replacing ' ' Values in a List with '0'

Tags: python, string, csv, null

I have a few `.csv` files that contain `NULL` values that are viewed as empty in the table. For example:

```
ID   Volts   Current   Watts
0    383               0
1    383     1         383
2    382     2         764
```

This `.csv` file is input into my program and converted to a list like this:

```
with open(inputPath + file) as inFile:
    csvFile = csv.reader(inFile)
    for row in csvFile:
        removeNull(row)
        print(row)
```

which essentially takes each row in `csvFile` and turns it into a list of values that looks something like this:

`['0', '383', '', '0']`, `['1', '383', '1', '383]`, etc.

*Note that the `NULL` values are now just empty strings, `''`.*

Then in relation to the snipet of the program above `removeNull()` is defined as:

```
def removeNull(row):
    nullIndex = row.index('')
    row.remove('')
    newRow = row.insert(nullIndex, '0')
    return newRow
```

which looks through the list (aka row) for empty strings, `''`, and notes their index as `nullIndex`. Then removes the empty string at said index, replaces it with `'0'` and returns the edited list.

**Question:** What exactly is wrong with my `removeNull()` function that causes it to only replace the first empty string, `''`, in a list? And how can I fix it so that it works for all empty strings in a list?

For clarification, a table like this with only *one* `NULL` value per row, or empty string once converted to a list, works just fine.

```
ID   Volts   Current   Watts
0    383               0
1    383     1         383
2    382     2         764
```

`['0', '383', '', '0']` *works fine.*

However if I have a table like this, with *multiple* `NULL` values per row, it will only replace the first empty string in the converted list and do nothing with the rest.

```
ID   Volts   Current   Watts
0                      0
1    383     1         383
2    382     2         764
```

`['0', '', '', '0']` *does not work fine.*

Comment: `newRow = row.insert(...)` looks fishy to me... `row.insert` should be returning `None`.

Comment: No need for a separate function.  Just add one line to your loop: `for row in csvFile:row = [item if item else '0' for item in row]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski  It isn't very obvious as I stated it above, but I need the separate function for other elements of the program. However your answer is completely correct so thank you regardless.

Comment: Why not read the CSVs with Pandas' `df = pandas.read_csv()` function??

Then you can replace all the Null values by simply `df.fillna(0, inplace = True)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `list.index` only returns index of the first occurrence of the item in the list. You can instead use a list comprehension on each row to do the replacement:

```
def removeNull(row):
    return ['0' if i=='' else i for i in row]
    #       |<- ternary op. ->|
```

The *ternary operator* in the list comprehension replaces blank strings with `'0'` while others are returned as they are.

On a side note, your function does not modify `row` *in-place*, therefore, you will need to assign the return value of the function to `row`:

```
for row in csvFile:
    row = removeNull(row)
    print(row)
```